# Scroll to div on click, loop around at end

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to do is introduce a button at the bottom right corner of the screen where users can click the button to scroll to the next 'section' div. Once they reach the last div in the html, it should loop back to the first `section` div.

My proposed solution is, when the page initially loads it gathers an array of items who's class name is 'section', then as the user hits the button it cycles through them scrolling the page. Is this possible?

Here is a link to the scrolling JavaScript I was trying to use.

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btnPrev').click(function() {
       var target;
       $(".section").each(function(i, element) {
         target = $(element).offset().top - 20;
         if (target - 40 > $(document).scrollTop()) {
           return false; // break
         }
       });
       $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: target}, 700);
    });
    $('.btnNext').click(function() {
       var target;
       $(".section").each(function(i, element) {
         target = $(element).offset().top - 20;
         if (target - 40 > $(document).scrollTop()) {
           return false; // break
         }
       });
       $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: target}, 700);
    });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    html {background-color: rgb(40,40,40);}
 .section {background-color:lightblue;margin: 40px 100px; padding:20px; height:300px;}
    .rowA {background-color:lightgreen;}

    /*Scroll Buttons*/
    .btnScroll {position: fixed; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5); width:40px; height:40px; text-align:center; line-height:40px; color:white; border-radius:4px;}
    .btnScroll:hover {background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2); cursor:pointer;}
    .btnScroll:active {background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5); cursor:pointer; selection:none;}
    .btnPrev {bottom: 70px; right: 20px;}
    .btnNext {bottom: 20px; right: 20px;}
    .noselect {
        -webkit-touch-callout: none; 
        -webkit-user-select: none; 
        -khtml-user-select: none; 
        -moz-user-select: none; 
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
</style>


<script src="rats.js"></script>

<div class="section rowA">Content Here</div>
<div class="section rowB">Content Here</div>
<div class="section rowA">Content Here</div>
<div class="section rowB">Content Here</div>
<div class="section rowA">Content Here</div>
<div class="section rowB">Content Here</div>
<div class="section rowA">Content Here</div>

<div class="btnScroll btnPrev noselect">&#8593;</div>
<div class="btnScroll btnNext noselect">&#8595;</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Somehow your jquery does not relate to your html at all. You attached a click event to link tags although you don't have a single `a`-tag on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your code a bit and came up with a solution that uses an index variable to keep track of the section the user is currently on. Both the up and down arrows are working now, and it also wraps around when the user reaches the first or last `.section` element.

Please try out the arrow buttons and tell me what you think.

**Live Demo:**

```js
var curr_el_index = 0;
var els_length = $(".section").length;

$('.btnNext').click(function () {
    curr_el_index++;
    if (curr_el_index >= els_length) curr_el_index = 0;
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(".section").eq(curr_el_index).offset().top - 20
    }, 700);
});

$('.btnPrev').click(function () {
    curr_el_index--;
    if (curr_el_index < 0) curr_el_index = els_length - 1;
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(".section").eq(curr_el_index).offset().top - 20
    }, 700);
});
```

```css
html {
     background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
 }
 .section {
     background-color:lightblue;
     margin: 40px 100px;
     padding:20px;
     height:300px;
 }
 .rowA {
     background-color:lightgreen;
 }
 /*Scroll Buttons*/
 .btnScroll {
     position: fixed;
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
     width:40px;
     height:40px;
     text-align:center;
     line-height:40px;
     color:white;
     border-radius:4px;
 }
 .btnScroll:hover {
     background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
     cursor:pointer;
 }
 .btnScroll:active {
     background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
     cursor:pointer;
     selection:none;
 }
 .btnPrev {
     bottom: 70px;
     right: 20px;
 }
 .btnNext {
     bottom: 20px;
     right: 20px;
 }
 .noselect {
     -webkit-touch-callout: none;
     -webkit-user-select: none;
     -khtml-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
     -ms-user-select: none;
     user-select: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section rowA">Content Here</div>
<div class="section rowB">Content Here</div>
<div class="section rowA">Content Here</div>
<div class="section rowB">Content Here</div>
<div class="section rowA">Content Here</div>
<div class="section rowB">Content Here</div>
<div class="section rowA">Content Here</div>
<div class="btnScroll btnPrev noselect">&#8593;</div>
<div class="btnScroll btnNext noselect">&#8595;</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/9x335kzg/3/

Answer (score 2):

I've taken a slightly different approach to answer your question. I changed the code to:

1) Initialise the first element with a `.selected` class.

2) On pager click, move the `.selected` class either up or down the specified elements.

3) After the class has been moved to the newly selected element, scroll to that element (the element with the class `.selected`).

Here is a fiddle of the outcome:

http://jsfiddle.net/rt13qnmm/

What we are doing now is managing the location of the `.selected` class and scrolling based on its new position.

All animations are completed using a custom function `scrollToSelected(offset)`

```
// Perform animation to the '.selected' class
function scrollToSelected(offset){
    $('html,body').stop(true).animate({
        scrollTop:$('.selected').offset().top + offset
    }, 'slow');
}
```

(This can be even further decoupled by removing the hard-coded `.selected` jQuery selector and passing it in as a parameter to the function instead, allowing you to scroll to any element throughout your site)